# comparing static char [] and const char *

Tags: c, char, string-comparison

```
static char a[255] = "\0";
and
const char *b = " ";
```

now when I assign "abc" to a and b, for a the remainig 252 bytes stay '\0' and for b its not like that. So, when I try to compare them, they come out to be different. 
One solution is to just compare till sizeof(b) as we do in strncmp(). 
Is there any other way of doing it? Probably by converting one to another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you compare strings? strcmp()?

Comment: Because first you declare while you initialize and then you redeclare and put 'a','b','c',somewhere in that array,When you initialize while you declare like what you did,you assign all the array elements to that character while when you assign a,b and c,you would be assigning them to some particular elements in the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `b` does not *have* a "remaining 252 bytes". `b` is created as a pointer to memory which contains the two characters `<space>` and `<nul>` and nothing else.

When you *assign* to `b`, you actually change the pointer to point at the four characters `a`, `b`, `c` and `<nul>`, but there's still nothing after there that you can safely use.

`strcmp` is the accepted way to compare strings in C, notwithstanding those namby-pamby `strncmp`-loving types that tell you it's unsafe<sup>*a</sup>, but they have no right coding in C in the first place :-)

---

<sup>*a</sup> It *is* unsafe if your strings may not be null-terminated. But then again, if they're not null-terminated, they're not technically strings. For processing strings, `strcmp` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: +1 for the "if they're not null-terminated, they're not technically strings".

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly you don't want to assign "abc" to b.  It will cause a memory leak with C-style strings when you change the value.

To compare you want to use the strcmp function.  It's in the  library.